# Kotlin - Viewpager doesn't show up when fragment is loaded

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, fragment, show

I got a problem that I'm trying to solve lately, but I just can't find a solution. 
In my project I got a fragment that inflates a layout, which has a `viewPager`. Until here everything is ok, but when I run the project to see it in my smartphone, everything show up but the `viewpager`. Am I missing something that I have to reconsiderate? This is what I got of my `viewpager` on the respective fragment in the `onCreateView` method:

```
    viewPager = conteudo_feridas.findViewById<View>(R.id.viewPagerGaleria) as ViewPager
    val adapter = ViewPageAdapter(activity!!.application)
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    viewPager.currentItem = images.size
```

In my `viewpager` I got the following code:

```
class ViewPageAdapter(private val context: Context) : PagerAdapter(){
    private var layoutInflater:LayoutInflater?= null

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object`
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return numeroFotos.size
        return dias.size
        return images.size
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        /**Set our vals to "inflate"**/
        layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val v = layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null)
        val nrFotos = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.dados_galeria_nr_fotos) as TextView
        val dados = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.dados_galeria_data) as TextView
        val image = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.image_view) as ImageView

   vp.addView(v, 0)

   return v
```

The layout of Viewpager, as well:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerGaleria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pageIndicatorView">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.rd.PageIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewPagerGaleria"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:piv_padding="50dp"
    app:piv_animationType="scale"
    app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPagerGaleria"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: Please, provide a code snipped of `ViewPageAdapter`

Comment: It's already in :)

Comment: could you add the layout xml file the viewpager is in? also there are three return statements in your getcount, I assume that is a mis-paste, make sure that getCount() returns a number > 0, also you can try changing the background color of the viewpager to make sure it is shown, and not just mis-inflated

Comment: oh and speaking of inflation, try doing this : val v = layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, container, false)  , it may just be that the inner view is not inflated correctly

Comment: It's on! Thanks.